# Questions about Flume Kafka source

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

When I use Flume Agent get data from Kafka source, and write data to `HDFS`, but some topics do not work well. The version of `Kafka` is `kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1`
. So, I run the command `bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk:port/kafka --`describe, the result is

> Topic:__consumer_offsets  PartitionCount:50   ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact
>
> Topic: __consumer_offsets Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr:
>   2,3,1 Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 1    Leader: 3   Replicas:
>   3,1,2 Isr: 3,1,2
>
> ...
>
> Topic: __consumer_offsets Partition: 48   Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr:
>   2,3,1 Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 49   Leader: 3   Replicas:
>   3,1,2 Isr: 3,1,2
>
> Topic:uniformAuthTopic    PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
>   Topic: uniformAuthTopic   Partition: 0    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr:
>   3,2,1 Topic: uniformAuthTopic Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas:
>   1,3,2 Isr: 1,3,2 Topic: uniformAuthTopic  Partition: 2    Leader:
>   2 Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 2,1,3

What's mean of Topic:__consumer_offsets?
Well, I run the command `bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zookeeper zk:port/kafka --group flume  --topic uniformAuthTopic`

> Group           Topic                          Pid Offset
>   logSize         Lag             Owner flume           uniformAuthTopic
>   0   14737892        20069753        5331861
>   flume_bj-cuadc-xhm-4f03-p7-hs22-client_a-01-1457010084974-e9d501b9-0
>   flume           uniformAuthTopic               1   14925444
>   20584430        5658986
>   flume_bj-cuadc-xhm-4f03-p7-hs22-client_a-01-1457010084974-e9d501b9-0
>   flume           uniformAuthTopic               2   21086401
>   21086988        587
>   flume_bj-yz302-f11-r720-8-1457492175405-54ad44d1-0

pid 0 and pid 1's owner is wrong, I do not know why the owner changed.
Please forgive my broken English!

Answer (score 0):

`_consumer_offsets` is a special topic used to track consumer offset commits. These used to be kept in Zookeeper, but are now kept this topic. According to **[the docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#impl_offsettracking)**:

> When the offset manager receives an OffsetCommitRequest, it appends the request to a special compacted Kafka topic named __consumer_offsets.